# On Ubuntu, I don't know if this is normal but top command is showing a lot of activity. The downloads I installed are in a pic I uploaded below

Tags: command-line, users, top

Top command shows this:

[image: Top command shows this.]

This typing for each picture thing is complicated because it's jumbling things together. But I did what I could to clean it up. I downloaded like 15 programs including blender, dolphin, Gnome, steam twice on accident(once through the store, twice through the terminal.) After shutting off PC while installing 2nd steam, no apps would start up after restarting until I reconfigured installs through terminal. Then decided to use Top command and now I'm worried about all this activity and don't know if it's normal for an these downloads.
[image]

Shows Top command in terminal

[image]

Shows multiple cores when it showed only one when I first installed Ubuntu.

[image]

Shows two software updaters when I should have one.

Comment: You've not provided a full picture of what you're seeing, but I see only a single root user and multiple processes (*running under that user account*)  Providing your actual Ubuntu product details (OS/product/release) and clues as to the *software* may also help us to provide more useful advice to you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the command you ran to show that screen. I assume it is `top`. I believe you have but one root user who is doing twenty things simultaneously.

Comment: Okay I am now, sorry.

Comment: I didn't know what to add in my description because I've done a lot and don't even know if there's a problem to fix now. I got the apps working now but an unsure about all of this activity in the top command. Not only that but my snap store disappeared after restart but I installed it again and everything seems to be working fine. Sorry, very new to Linux. I guess I'm trying to figure out whether not my PC is compromised in any way after downloading dolphin roms.

Comment: You can get text from top using `top -b -n 1 ` , which is far better than phoneshots. There is also the gnome screenshot tool ( press <kbd>Print Scrn</kbd> )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is normal.**

Your screenshot isn't showing multiple root users.  Your screenshot shows a list of processes with several of the processes being run by the root user.

Anyway, you can't have multiple users with the same username. The system won't allow it.

In terms of whether or not these processes are legitimate or necessary, it depends on what software you've installed.  But there is nothing standing out in your screenshot that indicates that you've been hacked. It's normal for the root user to have many concurrent tasks.

Comment: Thank you, next time I'll be more descriptive, doing this from mobile but probably shouldn't be. Tried giving you a vote but it says I must increase my rep. I looked over my question and it's a cluster (you know what). Thank you for the reassurance, next question will be better presented.

Comment: And it's done, I checked it, and thank you